# How to calculate the jaccard similarity

Tags: python, networkx

I want to use python to calculate the jaccard similarity for a network. I know the algorithm of the jaccard similarity is the length of the intersection divide the the length of the union. But I could not distinguish between these two ways:

the first way:

```
import networkx as nx
A=nx.complete_graph(5)
B=nx.complete_graph(8)
jaccard=len(set(A.nodes())&set(B.nodes()))/len(set(A.nodes())|set(B.nodes()))
```

the second way:

```
import networkx as nx
A=nx.complete_graph(5)
B=nx.complete_graph(8)
jaccard=len(set(A.edges())&set(B.edges()))/len(set(A.edges())|set(B.edges()))
```

Which way could I choose? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jaccard similarity is a metric defined for *sets*, not graphs. You could create a metric basic on Jaccard similarity that operates on graphs, but Jaccard similarity is not directly applicable to graphs.